# How does an ADSL modem tell which local client to associate with each response from a server?

Tags: networking, tcp, switch, tcpip, udp

Does an ADSL modem generate a random string for each request I make and when response comes it directs it to my computer (but not to my phone)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's a NATting router(most home adsl routers;I guessed you meant router from the word switch), It keeps a list of connections that shows which local port is used with each server and is associated with which local port comming from which client.
Otherwise it passes packets through as they came because they already have the right destination ip.

Comment: How does it keep the list? There are 3 local computers connecting to en.wikipedia.com:80 for example. So en.wikipedia.com:80 send 3 responses. So there is different randomly given local ports? So if I am Wikipedia server I can see their local ports?

Comment: for each outbound connection that is made, It allocates a random port. for example client A initiates a connection from local port 1025 to wikipedia.org:80, The router generates something like: A:1025:37892:208.80.154.225:80, 37892 is the random allocated port that wikipedia sees, The next client may get something like B:1309:42223:208.80.154.225:80, and the next may even use the same local port C:1025:18923:208.80.154.225:80, but all the responses get to the right client because the router changes the source port of the packet with the random one which is used for the lookups. outofcharacters

Comment: What else can server see rather than the local computer's port number?

Comment: What server sees is the routers public ip address and the random port it has chosen, noithing more, it can't usually detect if there are one or more clients connected from the same IP Address unless it inspects in OSI levels higher than 3 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model) and see if there are different browsers or different TCP parameters or something else that gives reason to beleive there are different clients connecting from the same ip which are of course very inaccurate..